# How are maven scopes mapped to ivy configurations by ivy

Tags: maven, ivy

Maven repositories, like [Maven Repository](http://mvnrepository.com/) offer the widest range of projects for dependency management.

Ivy offers the possibility to access maven repositories and download artifacts from there. There are only pom files in those repositories and no ivy.xml.

They can be retrieved with an [ivy resolver that runs in m2compatible mode](https://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/resolver/ibiblio.html).

```
<ibiblio name="maven2" m2compatible="true"/>
```

Especially for this Use-case I want to know:

- which scopes are available by default and what artifacts will they offer
- How is a maven scoped mapped to an ivy conf / configuration?

Comment: Would you like to know how a pom look like or what do you like to achieve?

Comment: I want to know how Ivy interprets pom files.

Comment: Ivy does not interpret pom files, cause it does not use pom file. It will use ivy configuration files.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The following two articles helped me to better understand how Maven and Ivy inter-operate

- http://www.symphonious.net/2010/01/25/using-ivy-for-dependency-management/
- http://lightguard-jp.blogspot.com/2009/04/ivy-configurations-when-pulling-from.html

Oddly, I never really understood ivy configurations, until it was explained how they can be used to simulate Maven scopes.

The following listis from the [www.symphonious.net link](http://www.symphonious.net/2010/01/25/using-ivy-for-dependency-management/) and illustrates the available configurations from pom-files/maven repositories:

- **default** runtime dependencies and master artifact can be used with
  this conf
- **master**       contains only the artifact published by this module itself,
  with no transitive dependencies
- **compile**      this is the default scope, used if none is specified.
  Compile dependencies are available in all classpaths
- **provided** this is much like compile, but indicates you expect the JDK
  or a container to provide it. It is only available on the compilation classpath, and is not transitive
- **runtime**      this scope indicates that the dependency is not required for
  compilation, but is for execution. It is in the runtime and test
  classpaths, but not the compile classpath
- **test**         this scope indicates that the dependency is not required for
  normal use of the application, and is only available for the test
  compilation and execution phases
- **system**       this scope is similar to provided except that you have to
  provide the JAR which contains it explicitly.
- **sources**      this configuration contains the source artifact of this
  module, if any   Source for the project
- **javadoc**      this configuration contains the javadoc artifact of this
  module, if any   JavaDoc for the project
- **optional** contains all optional dependencies