# Ivy do not download source, for each library

Tags: eclipse, ivy

I use Eclipse and Ivy.
Ivy in some library do not download source code.
For example, the library, such as Colt:

```
<dependency org="colt" name="colt" rev="1.2.0"/>
```

With H2 database, help this configuration:

```
<dependency org="com.h2database" name="h2" rev="1.3.164" conf="default->master,sources" />
```

How to set up ivy.xml that always download sources?

Answer (score 3):

You can specify a default configuration mapping to ensure that sources are always included

```
<configurations defaultconfmapping="default->master,sources"/>

<dependencies>
   <dependency org="colt" name="colt" rev="1.2.0"/>
   <dependency org="com.h2database" name="h2" rev="1.3.164"/>
</dependencies>
```

For more information on configuration mappings read this answer

[How are maven scopes mapped to ivy configurations by ivy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7104364/how-are-maven-scopes-mapped-to-ivy-configurations-by-ivy/7116577#7116577)

Comment: Because the colt module has no source jar. Check out the Maven Central search site: http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|colt|colt|1.2.0|jar. Whereas the h2 Maven module has both source and javadoc jars: http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|com.h2database|h2|1.3.164|jar