# IVY: Cannot resolve restlet dependency

Tags: ivy, restlet, dependency-management

I have a java project setup and wanted to use ivy as dependency management tool. However, I could not get the simplest one to work.

Here is the code I have:

**ivy.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<ivy-module version="2.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/schemas/ivy.xsd">
    <info
        organisation="de.fau.fsahoy"
        module="de.fau.fsahoy.android.api15"
        status="integration">
    </info>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency org="org.restlet.android" name="org.restlet" rev="2.1-RC5"/>
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

**ivysettings.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ivysettings >
    <settings defaultResolver="maven" />
    <resolvers>
        <chain name="maven" returnFirst="true">
            <ibiblio name="restlet" m2compatible="true" root="http://maven.restlet.org/" />
        </chain>
    </resolvers>

</ivysettings>
```

The errors I get are:

```
Impossible to resolve dependencies of de.fau.fsahoy#de.fau.fsahoy.android.api15;working@JonasErl-PC

Failed to load the descriptor for ivysettings.xml[*] in fsahoy-team-d-gitThe ivy file 'C:\Users\JonasErl\Code\fsahoy-team-d-git\ivysettings.xml' could not be parsed: null in file:/C:/Users/JonasErl/Code/fsahoy-team-d-git/ivysettings.xml


org.apache.ivyde.eclipse.IvyDEException: The ivy file 'C:\Users\JonasErl\Code\fsahoy-team-d-git\ivysettings.xml' could not be parsed: null in file:/C:/Users/JonasErl/Code/fsahoy-team-d-git/ivysettings.xml
    at org.apache.ivyde.eclipse.CachedIvy.getModuleDescriptor(CachedIvy.java:376)
    at org.apache.ivyde.eclipse.resolve.IvyResolveJob.run(IvyResolveJob.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
Caused by: java.text.ParseException: null in file:/C:/Users/JonasErl/Code/fsahoy-team-d-git/ivysettings.xml
    at org.apache.ivy.plugins.parser.xml.XmlModuleDescriptorParser$Parser.parse(XmlModuleDescriptorParser.java:301)
    at org.apache.ivy.plugins.parser.xml.XmlModuleDescriptorParser.parseDescriptor(XmlModuleDescriptorParser.java:116)
    at org.apache.ivy.plugins.parser.ModuleDescriptorParserRegistry.parseDescriptor(ModuleDescriptorParserRegistry.java:88)
    at org.apache.ivy.plugins.parser.AbstractModuleDescriptorParser.parseDescriptor(AbstractModuleDescriptorParser.java:48)
    at org.apache.ivyde.eclipse.CachedIvy.getModuleDescriptor(CachedIvy.java:368)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

You can have a look at the repository structure at [maven.restlet.org](http://maven.restlet.org)

These errormessages are not the very best unfortunately. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not reproduce your error....

- What version of ivy are you using?
- How are you invoking the ivy tasks?

## Test

### build.xml

```
<project name="demo" default="init" xmlns:ivy="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant">

    <target name="init">
        <ivy:resolve/>
    </target>

    <target name="clean">
        <ivy:cleancache/>
    </target>

</project>
```

### Build output

```
init:
[ivy:resolve] :: Apache Ivy 2.3.0-rc1 - 20120416000235 :: http://ant.apache.org/ivy/ ::
[ivy:resolve] :: loading settings :: file = /home/mark/tmp/ivysettings.xml
[ivy:resolve] :: resolving dependencies :: de.fau.fsahoy#de.fau.fsahoy.android.api15;working@mark-laptop
[ivy:resolve]   confs: [default]
[ivy:resolve]   found org.restlet.android#org.restlet;2.1-RC5 in restlet
[ivy:resolve] downloading http://maven.restlet.org/org/restlet/android/org.restlet/2.1-RC5/org.restlet-2.1-RC5.jar ...
[ivy:resolve] ..............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
[ivy:resolve] ................ (699kB)
[ivy:resolve] .. (0kB)
[ivy:resolve]   [SUCCESSFUL ] org.restlet.android#org.restlet;2.1-RC5!org.restlet.jar (1880ms)
[ivy:resolve] downloading http://maven.restlet.org/org/restlet/android/org.restlet/2.1-RC5/org.restlet-2.1-RC5-sources.jar ...
[ivy:resolve] ............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................... (738kB)
[ivy:resolve] .. (0kB)
[ivy:resolve]   [SUCCESSFUL ] org.restlet.android#org.restlet;2.1-RC5!org.restlet.jar(source) (971ms)
[ivy:resolve] :: resolution report :: resolve 1713ms :: artifacts dl 2864ms
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    |                  |            modules            ||   artifacts   |
    |       conf       | number| search|dwnlded|evicted|| number|dwnlded|
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    |      default     |   1   |   1   |   1   |   0   ||   2   |   2   |
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thank you. Now the resolving works.

However, it does not automatically add it as source and the android sdk is also not working.

Comment: @JonasGröger Sorry I don't understand. "add it as source"?  Sounds like a new question.

Comment: Yes somehow :) It downloads all the jars, like restlet.jar, restlet.src.jar and restlet.javadoc.jar. However, it does not add src and javadoc to the restlet.jar for completion and hover to see documentation and so on.

Comment: @JonasGröger Definately a second question. A quick answer attempt:....You need to include a configuration mapping on the ivy dependency, for example: conf="default". This will restrict the list of dependencies to those needed for compilation. I still don't understand the second part about adding to the restlet.jar and hovering.... Ivy doesn't change the dependencies in anyway, merely downloads them from remote repository.

Comment: Thank you for your help :) Every question was answered. Thanks also for the hint to configurations.

Comment: @JonasGröger Configurations are very powerful, but I found them tricky to figure out. If you're downloading from Maven repos the following will be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7104364/how-are-maven-scopes-mapped-to-ivy-configurations-by-ivy/7116577#7116577

Comment: Thank you for providing me the link. Im relatively new to build management and really dont know much about it. Any more resources that are very helpful?