# Ivy Configuration: Why the difference between these?

Tags: settings, ivy

```
<ivy-module version="2.0">
    <info organisation="com.travelclick" module="CoreWebServices" revision="4.1"/>
    <configurations defaultconfmapping="default">
        <conf name="runtime" visibility="public"/>
        <conf name="default" visibility="public"  extends="runtime"/>
    </configurations>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency org="com.travelclick"
            name="commons-all"
            rev="4.1"
            conf="default->default"/>

        <dependency org="com.sun.messaging.mq"
            name="jms"
            rev="4.5.2"
            conf="default->default"/>

        <dependency org="org.jboss.common"
            name="servlet-api"
            rev="4.2"
            conf="default->default"/>

        <dependency org="com.fiorano"
            name="framework"
            rev="2.0"
            conf="default->default"/>

        <dependency org="com.fiorano"
            name="fmq-client"
            rev="9.3.0"
            conf="default->default"/>

        <dependency org="commons-codec"
            name="commons-codec"
            rev="1.3"
            conf="default->default"/>

        <dependency org="commons-httpclient"
            name="commons-httpclient"
            rev="3.1"
            conf="default->default"/>

        <dependency org="commons-lang"
            name="commons-lang"
            rev="2.2"
            conf="default->default"/>

        <dependency org="commons-pool"
            name="commons-pool"
            rev="1.4"
            conf="default->default"/>
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

Note that all dependencies are configured as `default->default`.

In my `build.xml`, I have the following statements:

```
 <ivy:resolve conf="default"/>
 <ivy:cachepath pathid="all.libs" conf="default"/>
```

Note I'm using the *default* configuration.

I use the `all.libs` path to download the libraries into my war I'm building.

I get the following libraries in my war, which is what I want:

```
commons-all-4.1.jar
commons-codec-1.3.jar
commons-httpclient-3.1.jar
commons-lang-2.2.jar
commons-logging-1.0.4.jar
commons-pool-1.4.jar
fmq-client-9.3.0.jar
framework-2.0.jar
jms-4.5.2.jar
servlet-api-4.2.jar
```

Now, I'll remove the configuration information. This is the same `ivy.xml` with the `<configurations>` section removed and all the `conf=default->default` removed:

```
<ivy-module version="2.0">
    <info organisation="com.travelclick" module="CoreWebServices" revision="4.1"/>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency org="com.travelclick"
            name="commons-all"
            rev="4.1"/>

        <dependency org="com.sun.messaging.mq"
            name="jms"
            rev="4.5.2"/>

        <dependency org="org.jboss.common"
            name="servlet-api"
            rev="4.2"/>

        <dependency org="com.fiorano"
            name="framework"
            rev="2.0"/>

        <dependency org="com.fiorano"
            name="fmq-client"
            rev="9.3.0"/>

        <dependency org="commons-codec"
            name="commons-codec"
            rev="1.3"/>

        <dependency org="commons-httpclient"
            name="commons-httpclient"
            rev="3.1"/>

        <dependency org="commons-lang"
            name="commons-lang"
            rev="2.2"/>

        <dependency org="commons-pool"
            name="commons-pool"
            rev="1.4"/>
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

Naturally, I also have to change by `build.xml` to remove references to the default configuration:

```
 <ivy:resolve/>
 <ivy:cachepath pathid="all.libs"/>
```

But, now look what gets included:

```
commons-all-4.1.jar
commons-codec-1.3.jar
commons-httpclient-3.1.jar
commons-lang-2.2.jar
commons-logging-1.0.4.jar
commons-pool-1.4.jar
fmq-client-9.3.0.jar
framework-2.0.jar
jms-4.5.2.jar
servlet-api-4.2.jar

commons-httpclient-3.1-sources.jar
commons-codec-1.3-javadoc.jar
commons-codec-1.3-sources.jar
commons-lang-2.2-javadoc.jar
commons-lang-2.2-sources.jar
commons-pool-1.4-sources.jar
```

Why, when I set everything to *default*, only the actual jars downloaded and not the source and javadoc *jars*. Yet, when I removed all configuration, the javadoc and source *jars* also downloaded.

In fact, where is the configuration of the various jars in the Maven repository stored? I can see the javadoc and source in the Maven repository, but I didn't see anything about various *configurations*. How does Ivy know whether or not to include the *sources* and *javadoc* jars?

Comment: The mention of Maven in the last paragraph came as a late surprise. How is Maven involved here? Your Ivy module file above makes no mention of using a Maven repository. Does your Ivy settings file include such configuration?

Comment: @seh: Ivy can use Maven repositories for both getting jars and for distribution of jars. I use [Artifactory](http://www.jfrog.com/home/v_artifactory_opensource_overview). Some of those jars are company owned jars and aren't in the standard Maven repo. I added them into our Artifactory repo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no standard default [configuration](https://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/trunk/ivyfile/configurations.html) in ivy. Each  ivy file defines its own set of `conf`s in the `<configuration> ..</configuration>` section.

In your **first example** you defined `default` and mapped it to the `default` configuration of your artifacts. These dependencies are maven artifacts and ivy maps a maven scope to `default` (Ivy reads the maven pom file and creates an ivy file for that in the cache). So basically you were just lucky, that the `default` conf existed in the ivy file for the configuration.

The conf `default` is a mapped maven scope and does not exist as a pre-defined standard `conf` in ivy.

In your **second example** you omit the `conf="default->default"`, [which is equivalent to](https://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/trunk/ivyfile/configurations.html#defaultconfmapping) `conf="*->*"` and means: map everything in the dependency to every `conf` in this ivy file.

[This question answers how ivy maps maven scopes to ivy configurations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7104364/how-are-maven-scopes-mapped-to-ivy-configurations-by-ivy).

In Short:

- `default` maps to the maven scope default which just references the jar
- declaring no scopes maps to the ivy configuration `*`, which references all available configurations and therefore all available maven artifacts.

Comment: Ah! Thanks. Now it's makes sense. I was looking for configuration information in the repo, but I goes that's just an Ivy thing. What you're saying is that the _default_ configuration isn't the actual _default_ configuration in Ivy.

Comment: Just wanted to add that the links were also very useful. Thanks again. It clears up a lot of my confusion about Ivy.