# Can't Download json-lib in Ivy

Tags: ivy

I want to download json-lib-2.3-jdk15.jar. I find ivy don't have classifier tag, so I use maven one, below is the ivy.xml

```
<ivy-module version="2.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/schemas/ivy.xsd"
       xmlns:m="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/maven">
    <info organisation="xxxx" module="xxx" status="integration"/>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency org="net.sf.json-lib" name="json-lib" rev="2.3"> 
            <artifact name="json-lib" type="jar" m:classifier="jdk15"/>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

And ivysetting.xml

```
<ivysettings>
    <settings defaultResolver="default" />
    <include url="${ivy.default.settings.dir}/ivysettings-public.xml" />
    <include url="${ivy.default.settings.dir}/ivysettings-shared.xml"/>
    <include url="${ivy.default.settings.dir}/ivysettings-local.xml" />
    <include url="${ivy.default.settings.dir}/ivysettings-main-chain.xml"/>

    <caches artifactPattern="[organisation]/[module]/([branch]/)[type]s/([platform]/)[artifact]-[revision](.[ext])" />
    <resolvers>
        <filesystem name="local">
            <ivy
                pattern="${ivy.local.default.root}/[organisation]/[module]/([branch]/)[revision]/ivy.xml" />
            <artifact
                pattern="${ivy.local.default.root}/[organisation]/[module]/([branch]/)[revision]/[type]s/([platform]/)[artifact](.[ext])" />
        </filesystem>
        <ibiblio name="public" m2compatible="true" usepoms="true" pattern="[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]" /> 
        <chain name="default" returnFirst="true">
                    <resolver ref="local" />
            <resolver ref="public"/>
        </chain>
    </resolvers>
</ivysettings>
```

But I still can't download it. It seems like m:classifier not work. Any suggestion about this? Thanks.

**I finally find the root reason**. I should not use

```
xmlns:m="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/maven
```

I should use

```
xmlns:m="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/extra
```

Another thing, in my case, I was add "conf" distribute in "artifact" tag, which will make the jar download fail. So do not add "conf" in "artifact".

Answer (score 1):

Works for me.... What version of ivy are you using?

The following example contains some suggested enhancements

## Example

```
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.2
Apache Ivy 2.3.0-rc2
```

### ivy.xml

```
<ivy-module version="2.0" xmlns:m="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/maven">
    <info organisation="xxxx" module="xxx"/>
    <configurations>
        <conf name="jdk15"   description="JDK 1.5 dependencies"/>
    </configurations>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency org="net.sf.json-lib" name="json-lib" rev="2.3" conf="jdk15->master"> 
            <artifact name="json-lib" type="jar" m:classifier="jdk15"/>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

Notes:

- It's always a good idea to use configurations. In this case I've created one called "jdk15" to group the files with jdk15 classifiers
- The remote "master" configuration is special and contains no transitive dependencies (See following link for explanation)
- [How are maven scopes mapped to ivy configurations by ivy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7104364/how-are-maven-scopes-mapped-to-ivy-configurations-by-ivy/7116577#7116577)

### ivysettings.xml

```
<ivysettings>
    <settings defaultResolver="central" />
    <resolvers>
        <ibiblio name="central" m2compatible="true"/> 
    </resolvers>
</ivysettings>
```

Notes:

- This is a minimal ivy settings file. (In fact you could omit the file and it would be functionally the same).
- Are you using the "local" resolver? In my experience it's unnecessary (Unless you're publishing artifacts during your build)

Comment: It's a Maven thing. Used to specify additional artefacts that might be stored in the Maven repository. In this case see: http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22net.sf.json-lib%22%20AND%20a%3A%22json-lib%22%20AND%20v%3A%222.3%22%20AND%20l%3A%22jdk15%22

Comment: not sure of that, i dug into it...m:classifier as ti turns out is actually the way ivy knows that an artifact has a classifier https://github.com/apache/ant-ivy/blob/09b1a632c17b34650d2bcf748be14690c9882e52/src/java/org/apache/ivy/plugins/parser/m2/PomModuleDescriptorBuilder.java#L320 and then that is used in it's xsl  https://github.com/apache/ant-ivy/blob/09b1a632c17b34650d2bcf748be14690c9882e52/src/java/org/apache/ivy/plugins/resolver/packager/packager.xsl#L195  what a hack that is!