# Ivy test configuration in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ant, ivy, ivyde

I have an ivy dependency management to work both under eclipse and with ant.

How should I configure the test dependencies to be available for eclipse?

my current configuration is:

```
<configurations>
  ...
  <conf name="test" visibility="public"/>
</configurations>

<dependencies>
  ...
  <dependency org="org.testng" name="testng" rev="6.7" conf="test->provided" transitive="false"/>
</dependencies>
```

With that configuration TestNG is not "retrieved". I'm using IvyDE, and  'Select every configuration' is set.

Comment: `<dependency org="org.testng" name="testng" rev="6.7" conf="test->default" transitive="false"/>` solved the issue, but I don't understand why... :-(

Comment: Every maven project should have the one of the following scopes:compile, provided, runtime, test (http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope) ... and testNG has its pom.xml

Comment: See the following answer for information on how Maven scopes related to ivy configurations: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7104364/how-are-maven-scopes-mapped-to-ivy-configurations-by-ivy/7116577#7116577