# including jar file in ivy dependencies

Tags: java, netbeans, ant, jar, ivy

I am using netbeans 7.1.1 and ivy together.
I have ivy.xml file as follows :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ivy-module version="2.0">
    <info module="Laitsv3second" organisation="Laitsv3second" revision="1.0"/>
<dependency org="org.apache.httpcomponents" name="httpclient" rev="latest.integration">
</dependency>
</ivy-module>
```

Now the problem is as follows :
my project uses log4j library as well. and when I run the project I get an error as follows :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpUriRequest
```

the downloaded httpclient library contains this class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest.java but this is an interface and hence this error is arising. I observed that ivy links sources.jar in ivy libraries which contains java interface but what I want is httpclient.jar to be included in the project which is a compiled version of sources containing `.class` files. Is there any way this is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above mentioned error is because ivy libraries are not added to the java classpath. This issue is reported on ivyBeans website. [Here are the details of the issue.](https://code.google.com/p/ivybeans/issues/detail?id=58)
As stated here I too solved this problem by turning 'compile on save' option off in the netbeans. I thought this solution might help others hence posted.

Answer (score 1):

First of all your ivy file is invalid. You're missing the enclosing "dependencies" tag:

```
<ivy-module version="2.0">
    <info module="Laitsv3second" organisation="Laitsv3second" revision="1.0"/>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency org="org.apache.httpcomponents" name="httpclient" rev="latest.integration"/>
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

What I suspect is your real issue is that you are not setting your classpath correctly within your ANT build. Impossible to diagnose further based on the available information.

What I would suggest is use the working example in the following answer:

- [Class not found with Ant, Ivy and JUnit - error in build.xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15979391/class-not-found-with-ant-ivy-and-junit-error-in-build-xml/15982144#15982144)

I recommend checking out how it uses configurations in the ivy file and ivy tasks like:

- [cachepath](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/cachepath.html) - Used to create an ANT path, based on the configuration in ivy
- [report](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/report.html) - Used to document how ivy resolves its dependencies. Report created for each configuration in the ivy file
- [retrieve](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/retrieve.html) - Used to install resolved files locally. Useful when building a distribution
- [manifestclasspath](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/manifestclasspath.html) - Lesser known ANT task, just very powerful when combined with an ivy retrieve.

Comment: Sorry I pasted wrong. my ivy.xml was fine. Yes you are right my classpath is not getting set correctly by ant somehow, it doesn't incorporate ivy libraries i don't know why. Let me check your example and my build.xml and I'll get back to you. Thanks

Comment: I have been trying to fix this classpat problem since 2 days. I have jhall.jar on my ivy libraries and still I am getting an error saying "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/help/HelpSet" at runtime. Trying to find the cause.

Comment: @tejas That's a new question. As stated above impossible to tell, classpath management is done by the ivy tasks in the build file. Sorry can't help further.

Comment: I figured out the solution myself. It was netbeans' problem. It has a compile on save feature which is ON by default, and that adds only those libraries on classpath which are added through netbeans. It doesn't add ivy libraries on classpath and that was the cause of error. Thanks for helping though.

Comment: @tejas If you accept an answer, we know your problem is solved.... Additionally it's quite acceptable to post your own answer to a question, which may be of use to others.