# How to include an external jar lib in my Ant build

Tags: java, ant, build

I have the following `build.xml`:

```
<project>

<target name="clean">
    <delete dir="./build"/>
</target>

<target name="compile">
    <mkdir dir="./build/classes"/>          
    <javac srcdir="./src" destdir="./build/classes"/>                   
</target>

<target name="jar">
    <mkdir dir="./build/jar"/>
    <jar destfile="./build/jar/DependencyFinder.jar" basedir="./build/classes">
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="DependencyFinder" value="main"/>
        </manifest>
    </jar>
</target>

<target name="run">
    <java jar="./build/jar/DependencyFinder.jar" classname="${main-class}" fork="true"/>                    
</target>

</project>
```

Here is my directory structure:

/build
/lib
/MagicFolder
/Src
/build.xml

Folder `src` contains `.java` files.

Path to `MagicFolder` should be an input parameter.

`lib` has external .jar library which should be included in my build.

`build` folder which will have compiled `.jar and`.class` files

QUESTION:
How should I change my `build.xml`? My `build.xml` should:

1. Add external lib `./lib/jbl.jar`
2. When I run my application put 2 input parametrs for my application

Answer (score 47, accepted):

If you need to add a jar to classpath to compile the code (sorry, it isn't quite clear what you're asking for), then you need to change `<javac>` task to look like this:

```
<javac srcdir="./src" destdir="./build/classes">   
    <classpath>
        <pathelement path="lib/jbl.jar"/>
    </classpath>
</javac>
```

Or if you need to add contents of `jbl.jar` to the jar you are creating, then you need to change your `<jar>` task to look like this:

```
<jar destfile="./build/jar/DependencyFinder.jar" basedir="./build/classes>
    <zipgroupfileset dir="lib" includes="jbl.jar" />
    <manifest>
        <attribute name="DependencyFinder" value="main"/>
        <attribute name="Main-Class" value="org.ivanovpavel.YourMainClass"/>
    </manifest>
</jar>
```

To add arguments to `<java>` call, use nested `<arg>` elements:

```
<target name="run">
    <java jar="./build/jar/DependencyFinder.jar:lib/jbl.jar" classname="dependencyfinder.DependencyFinder">  
        <arg value="Alexander Rosenbaum"/>
        <arg value="Dmitry Malikov"/>
    </java>                  
</target>
```

Comment: When I'm start run task, I'm have error message: Cannot user 'jar' and 'classname' attributes in same command

Comment: Big thanks!
Could you help me with one more problem here?
I'm have problems with run task. I got message after execute:
[java] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/ooLab/language/javaByteCode/JavaByteCodeException
bla bla bla
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundExecption: org.ooLab.language.JavaByteCode.JavaByteCodeException

all classes of ooLab place in external jar lib ./lib/jbl.jar

Comment: Could you change code in your comment? Of course I'm will set accept :) good example of input paramentrs

Comment: Your change didnt helps me :(

Comment: Didnt helps :(
<target name="run">
    <java jar="./build/jar/DependencyFinder.jar" fork="true">  
  <classpath>
            <pathelement path="./lib/jbl.jar"/>
   <pathelement path= "./build/jar/DependencyFinder.jar"/>
        </classpath>
        <arg value="./MagicFolder/"/>
        <arg value="C"/>        
    </java>

Comment: Errors are the same:
[java] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/ooLab/language/javaByteCode/JavaByteCodeException bla bla bla Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundExecption: org.ooLab.language.JavaByteCode.JavaByteCodeException


http://cs320621.vk.me/v320621781/4f11/mvr7KLULtL0.jpg

Comment: http://cs320621.vk.me/v320621781/4f1a/s3u7vtWVpj8.jpg

I'm very nervous now. Tomorrow - deadline :(

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways to run a java program. Using the "jar" option is the most convenient and is called an executable jar, however in order to make it work you need to specify both the Main class and classpath in the manifest file as follows:

```
<jar destfile="${jar.file}" basedir="${classes.dir}">
    <manifest>
        <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${jar.main.class}" />
        <attribute name="Class-Path" value="${jar.classpath}" />
    </manifest>
</jar>
```

For a more detailed answer on how to do this see:

[Execute Java programs in a consistent environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19442706/execute-java-programs-in-a-consistent-environment/19468304#19468304)

Answer (score 2):

try with this:

```
<target name="jar" depends="clean,compile" >
   <jar destfile="./build/jar/DependencyFinder.jar">
    <fileset dir="./lib" includes="jbl.jar,mysql*.jar" />
    <fileset dir="./build/classes" excludes="**/form/*.class,**/orm/*.class,**/org/w3/xmldsig/*.class"/>
   </jar>
</target>
```