# Ant error "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jna/Library"

Tags: java, ant, noclassdeffounderror, jna, runtimeexception

I have a Java program using number of external libraries. The program compiles and runs in the Eclipse IDE without any issues. However, when using an ant build.xml, compilation works fine, but throws the following exception when during run time.

```
run:
 [java] Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jna/Library
 [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
 [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
 [java]     at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
 [java]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
 [java]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
 [java]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
 [java]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
 [java]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 [java]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
 [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
 [java]     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
 [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
 [java]     at org.freedesktop.gstreamer.Gst.getVersion(Unknown Source)
 [java]     at org.freedesktop.gstreamer.Gst.init(Unknown Source)
 [java]     at org.freedesktop.gstreamer.Gst.init(Unknown Source)
 [java]     at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
 [java]     at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
 [java]     at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
 [java]     at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
 [java]     at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
 [java]     at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6539)
 [java]     at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
 [java]     at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6304)
 [java]     at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2239)
 [java]     at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
 [java]     at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)
 [java]     at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
 [java]     at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4904)
 [java]     at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4535)
 [java]     at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4476)
 [java]     at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2283)
 [java]     at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
 [java]     at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
 [java]     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760)
 [java]     at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
 [java]     at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
 [java]     at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
 [java]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 [java]     at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
 [java]     at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84)
 [java]     at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733)
 [java]     at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
 [java]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 [java]     at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
 [java]     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730)
 [java]     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
 [java]     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
 [java]     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
 [java]     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
 [java]     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
 [java]     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
 [java] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jna.Library
 [java]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
 [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
 [java]     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
 [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
 [java]     ... 52 more
```

The build script I'm using is given below.

```
<property name="src.dir"     value="src/org"/>
<property name="build.dir"   value="build"/>
<property name="classes.dir" value="${build.dir}/classes"/>
<property name="jar.dir"     value="${build.dir}/jar"/>
<property name="lib.dir"     value="Libs" />

<property name="main-class"  value="org.ai.receiver.DashboardLauncher"/>

<target name="clean">
    <delete dir="${build.dir}"/>
</target>

<target name="compile">
    <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}"/>
    <javac srcdir="${src.dir}/ai/receiver:${src.dir}/freedesktop/gstreamer" destdir="${classes.dir}" includeantruntime="false">
    <classpath>
        <fileset dir="${lib.dir}">
            <include name="**/*.jar" />
        </fileset>
    </classpath>
    </javac>
</target>
<target name="jar" depends="compile">
    <mkdir dir="${jar.dir}"/>
    <jar destfile="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar" basedir="${classes.dir}">
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main-class}"/>
        </manifest>
    </jar>
</target>

<target name="run" depends="jar">
    <java jar="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar" fork="true">
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="Libs/jna.jar:Libs/jna-platform.jar:Libs/swt.jar"/>
            <fileset dir="${lib.dir}">
                <include name="**/*.jar" />
            </fileset>
         </classpath>
    </java>
</target>
<target name="clean-build" depends="clean,jar"/>
<target name="main" depends="clean,run"/>
```

The required external libraries "jna.jar", "jna-platform.jar" and "swt.jar" files are located in the "Lib" directory.

It seems to me that these external libraries are not properly loading during the run time, yet they are properly linked during the compile time. A similar issue is discussed in this [github issue tracker](https://github.com/WebcamStudio/webcamstudio/issues/98), but the discussion doesn't provide a proper solution.

Could you please help me to fix this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: Are other external libraries working fine? If not, I suspect you are actually asking about [how to include dependencies in your own jar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19642388/996081)

Comment: Thanks, the issue was solved by adding <zipgroupfileset dir="Libs" includes="*.jar" /> to the jar target. Posted the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

This issue was resolved by changing the target for .jar as follows:

```
<target name="jar" depends="compile">
    <mkdir dir="${jar.dir}"/>
    <jar destfile="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar" basedir="${classes.dir}">
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main-class}"/>
        </manifest>
        <zipgroupfileset dir="Libs" includes="*.jar" />
    </jar>
</target>
```