# Transiting Maven dependencies to Ant

Tags: java, maven, ant, mule, mule-component

I am working on a JAVA project that is Ant based and I need to make it Mule enabled so that I can implement RAML based web-service in this. And to make it Mule enabled, I have collected number of jars required and finally Mule flow is working fine. But, using any different Mule component requires further dependencies hence, it is becoming difficult to collect all those every time and then I thought to Mavenize my project first but that I am not allowed to do. So, I need to know that is there any way I can use POM.xml together with Ant or any other way so that I don't need to collect required jars rather it get managed automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be needing pom.xml unless you mavenise your project but you can use Apache IVY to do the dependency management. You can maintain an ivy.xml file and let your ant script include its execution while building the project. You can also have a ivy settings.xml to take care of patterns/locations.

-Shanky G.

Comment: Thank you Shanky, Actually I am working in the same way as you have suggested. And right now I am dealing with the ivysettings.xml because it looks like very important because several aspects has enforced me to look into it.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used it yet but for Ant there is [Ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) which can work with Maven Central. Maybe it can help in your situation as well.

Comment: And here's an example ivy project: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15979391/class-not-found-with-ant-ivy-and-junit-error-in-build-xml/15982144#15982144

Comment: Hi Puce, thanks for replying quickly. I have started researching on it and till now I haven't completed what I wanted actually but it seems promising. Well, I am towards the result and may be I can come up with further problems... :)