# Include external jars in ant

Tags: java, ant, jar

I am new to writing build files and currently I am writing the ant for my project. The issue I am facing is to include the jar to in ant build file.
As per the standard 'ant build' the jars need to be kept in lib folder. But the issue is the jar is very huge, more than 100 GB of size and hence cannot be kept in GitHub.

I have put that in another repository and want to include that in my build file.

Could anyone please let me know how to include the jars in my 'pathelement location' from the url.

Comment: I have a build.xml(ant based) which requires some jar from nexus to get copied in existing lib folder. i.e when it builds it should copy the jar from nexus with some version defined & then copy in lib & do compilation. like happen in maven we define the artifact & its version . If changed will automatically download it from maven repo. how can i do this in ant based builds?

Comment: You could try Ivy. It's a bit like Maven but Ant based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Apache ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) is a 3rd party dependency manager, a powerful feature built into more modern Java build tools like Maven and Gradle.

The following answer gives a detailed example, using ivy to manage classpaths and help in the creation of an executable jar.

- [Class not found with Ant, Ivy and JUnit - error in build.xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15979391/class-not-found-with-ant-ivy-and-junit-error-in-build-xml/15982144#15982144)

You mentioned the use of another repository. Presumably this is a Maven repository manager like Nexus or Artifactory. Ivy is capable of downloading from these. (which would be another question :-))