# ant, failed downloads that are all javadoc related

Tags: java, ant, ivy

I'm not super familiar with java, but I've got a a project I'm working on, on my work computer everything works as expected (builds, runs, ect), however, when I `ant -v` on my home computer, I get the following.

```
[ivy:retrieve] :: problems summary ::
[ivy:retrieve] :::: WARNINGS
[ivy:retrieve]      [NOT FOUND  ] javax.mail#mail;1.4!mail.jar(javadoc) (99ms)
[ivy:retrieve]  ==== public: tried
[ivy:retrieve]    http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/mail/mail/1.4/mail-1.4-javadoc.jar
[ivy:retrieve]      [NOT FOUND  ] junit#junit;4.8.1!junit.jar(javadoc) (47ms)
[ivy:retrieve]  ==== public: tried
[ivy:retrieve]    http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/junit/junit/4.8.1/junit-4.8.1-javadoc.jar
[ivy:retrieve]      [NOT FOUND  ] com.mockrunner#mockrunner;0.3.1!mockrunner.jar(source) (47ms)
[ivy:retrieve]  ==== public: tried
[ivy:retrieve]    http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/mockrunner/mockrunner/0.3.1/mockrunner-0.3.1-sources.jar
[ivy:retrieve]      [NOT FOUND  ] com.mockrunner#mockrunner;0.3.1!mockrunner.jar(javadoc) (56ms)
[ivy:retrieve]  ==== public: tried
[ivy:retrieve]    http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/mockrunner/mockrunner/0.3.1/mockrunner-0.3.1-javadoc.jar
[ivy:retrieve]      ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[ivy:retrieve]      ::              FAILED DOWNLOADS            ::
[ivy:retrieve]      :: ^ see resolution messages for details  ^ ::
[ivy:retrieve]      ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[ivy:retrieve]      :: javax.mail#mail;1.4!mail.jar(javadoc)
[ivy:retrieve]      :: junit#junit;4.8.1!junit.jar(javadoc)
[ivy:retrieve]      :: com.mockrunner#mockrunner;0.3.1!mockrunner.jar(source)
[ivy:retrieve]      :: com.mockrunner#mockrunner;0.3.1!mockrunner.jar(javadoc)
[ivy:retrieve]      ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was fixed by going into the ivy.xml file and changing dependencies as follows

### WAS (Didn't Work)

```
<dependency org="javax.mail" name="mail" rev="1.4"/>
<dependency org="junit" name="junit" rev="4.8.1"/>
<dependency org="com.mockrunner" name="mockrunner" rev="0.3.1"/>
```

### IS (Fixed)

```
<dependency org="javax.mail" name="mail" rev="1.4" conf="default->master"/>
<dependency org="junit" name="junit" rev="4.8.1" conf="default->master"/>
<dependency org="com.mockrunner" name="mockrunner" rev="0.3.1" conf="default->master"/>
```

Comment: The solution works by telling ivy to ignore transitive dependencies (in this case javadocs). I suspect a "conf='default'" mapping might also work. For more details on how configurations work with Maven repositories see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7104364/how-are-maven-scopes-mapped-to-ivy-configurations-by-ivy/7116577#7116577