# How do I convert my ivy code to maven if I use a regular expression?

Tags: regex, maven, build, ivy

My Ivy declaration is:

```
<dependency org="pmd" name="pmd" rec="4.2.5" conf="static-analysis->default">
     <exclude module="xom|xml-apis|jdom|dom4j|xercesImpl|ant|junit" 
      matcher="regexp" />
</dependency>
```

Right now I have that in Maven as:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>pmd</groupId>
   <artifactId>pmd</artifactId>
   <version>4.2.5</version>
   <exclusions>
      <exclusion></exclusion>
   </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

I am not sure how get the exclusion right. I am also not sure how convert the conf attribute from Ivy either.

Comment: Make a list of equitable forms in Ivy that exist for Maven. Find out how to parse Ivy declarations. Construct the Maven line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one concentrates only on dependency management, Maven and Ivy are tools with a similar mission, but quite different implementations.

I don't believe that regular expression exclusions are supported by Maven, although it appears some form of wildcard support was added in version 3, See [MNG-3832](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-3832)

My advice is to adopt the simplest solution possible, so just explicitly list the dependencies you don't want:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>pmd</groupId>
   <artifactId>pmd</artifactId>
   <version>4.2.5</version>
   <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>*</groupId>
        <artifactId>xom</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>*</groupId>
        <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>*</groupId>
        <artifactId>jdom</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
      ..
      ..
   </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Configuration mapping is very tricky to translate, because the concept does not exist in Maven. Maven has a fixed number of "scopes" whereas configurations are often used to simulate scopes, but are not as limited. For more background infomration I recommend

- [How are maven scopes mapped to ivy configurations by ivy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7104364/how-are-maven-scopes-mapped-to-ivy-configurations-by-ivy/7116577#7116577)