# ivy configurations - how to manage test utilities?

Tags: java, testing, ivy, configurationsection

I'll present a simplified version of our problem, but know that we have **way** more than 2 projects, and so on.

So, at our job, we have 2 projects -

- `A`
- `B`

where `B` depends on `A` through ivy.
Recently we added configurations to the mix, mainly `default` and `test`.
The problem we ran into is that in `A` we have test utilities, which `B` needs in order to run it's own tests, so we need `B` to get these utilities from `A`.
We've thought of 2 ways to solve this:

- make the `test` configuration public
- create a new conf - `test-utils` - that will be public, and `A` will publish it's own tests under that configuration

The problem is that both solutions seem somewhat forced, and I wanted to get an idea how people do this world-wide.

Any ideas?

Comment: I would suggest you create a 3rd project called "test utils" and get it to publish it's artifact into your repository. That way the same sort of tests can be run in Project A and B, pulling dependencies independently and increasing decoupling.

Comment: The problem is that we have many more such pairs of projects, and I don't want to create so many new projects, and refactor the relevant code

Answer (score 0):

> **Note:**
>   This answer assumes you're using a Maven repository manager. (Something
>   like Nexus or Artifactory).

I suggest that you upload an additional "test-utils" artifact when publishing Project A. This means the primary Maven artifact would be:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
  <artifactId>ProjectA</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

and the second artifact is:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
  <artifactId>ProjectA</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.1</version>
  <classifier>test-utils</classifier>
</dependency>
```

For more details on how ivy publishes and retrieves additional artifacts from a Maven repository I would suggest reading the following:

- [how to publish 3rdparty artifacts with ivy and nexus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5111831/how-to-publish-3rdparty-artifacts-with-ivy-and-nexus/5115447#5115447)
- [ivy:install from maven with classifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24943065/ivyinstall-from-maven-with-classifiers/24946226#24946226)

Comment: See my comment to your comment

Comment: @orirab Yes, and I provided an answer that did not involve creating a new project. I did assume that you're using a Maven repository (based on the law of averages). Maven has only limited support for configurations.... Now... if you're using an ivy repository then using a second "test" configuration suddenly becomes an option.

Comment: I just re-read your answer, and it seems I didn't understand it before. But if I get you now, you're suggesting I follow the second course I suggested in the question, right?
To clarify, the basic problem we have is that the tests and the utils are mixed together, and I don't want to separate them right now.