How to specify the jakarta classifier for PrimeFaces in Ivy?
I'm trying to use the primefaces-jakarta version of PrimeFaces in my project. In Maven, I can easily specify the classifier like this:
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
    <version><!-- 10.0.0, 11.0.0, 12.0.0, etc --></version>
    <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
</dependency>

However, I'm using Apache Ivy for dependency management, and I'm not sure how to specify the classifier in Ivy. Here's what I currently have in my ivy.xml:
 <dependencies>
        <dependency org="org.primefaces" name="primefaces" rev="14.0.2"/>
  </dependencies>

When I run my build script, it resolves to the default primefaces artifact which uses javax instead of jakarta. How can I configure Ivy to download the primefaces artifact with the jakarta classifier?

Looks like Ivy doesn't play nicely with classifiers but some workarounds: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24943065/ivyinstall-from-maven-with-classifiers
