# Nexus Ivy Maven : Second Level Dependencies Ignores Transitive

Tags: java, maven, ivy, nexus

1.) I have  a Project1  with this ivy dependency :

```
<dependency org="xalan" name="serializer" rev="2.7.1" transitive="false" conf="compile->default" />
```

This project  brings  serializer.jar (just only this jar, **OK!** )

2.) In a second one Project (Proyect2)   i put the next dependency :

```
<dependency org="com.net" name="Project1" rev="latest.integration" conf="default->default;compile->compile;runtime->runtime" transitive="true">
</dependency>
```

This "Project 2" brings :

1. Project 1
2. Serializer.jar
3. xml-apis.jar

   **Despite of putting transite to false in xalan dependency.**

I haven't this behaviour in my Eclipse + IVEDe environment,  just only  with Nexus and Maven.... It seems to be wrong because on Project1 i set xalan transitive to false.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following dependency in Project 1 and see if that fixes the problem:

```
<dependency org="xalan" name="serializer" rev="2.7.1" conf="compile->master" />
```

See the following answer on how Ivy interprets Maven modules and scopes:

- [How are maven scopes mapped to ivy configurations by ivy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7104364/how-are-maven-scopes-mapped-to-ivy-configurations-by-ivy/7116577#7116577)

I'm not a fan of switching off transitive dependencies. I think it's much better to rely on configuration mappings and if absolutely necessary include an exclude statement to remove an objectionable dependency.

Comment: hi!  Another way to fix the problem is to exclude xml-apis .  For me it worked this way  ( exclude module='xml-apis') , but yes sending master configuration to compile is another option.  But, what i want to mean is that in the way i defined the dependency transitive="false" no third party library should be given....On my local environment (with IVYDe Pluggin for Eclipse) Ivy brings me JUST serializer.jar , but with Maven & Nexus brings me Serializer & Xml-apis .... I don't know why.. The logic behaviour is local's !:-)! with no transitiveness...