# Download dependency of dependency using ivy

Tags: ivy

Am a beginner in Ant+Ivy . So any help is appreciated.
In my ivy.xml, I have listed the dependency section and the jar I need to build.

```
<dependency org="org.xxx" name="abc" rev="1.0.0"  transitive="false"/>
```

This downloads abc.jar. But the problem is abc.jar is dependent on 50 other jar files to work. So how can I download them all ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have set the transitive flag to false, telling ivy not to download dependencies.

Try this instead:

```
<dependency org="org.xxx" name="abc" rev="1.0.0" conf="default"/>
```

See related answer:

- [Nexus Ivy Maven : Second Level Dependencies Ignores Transitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26178442/nexus-ivy-maven-second-level-dependencies-ignores-transitive/26204055#26204055)

Comment: before I received your answer, I tried with transitive="true" - It didnt work; Now I tried your answer and that didnt work either. Earlier, this abc.jar and its 50 dependencies were on one shared folder and my project was pulling from share and it worked fine. Now I put abc.jar on Nexus and trying to download through ivy but my project fails because it is not getting its dependencies of abc.jar. Should I explicitly list all of them in my ivy.xml to download the dependencies of dependency?

Comment: @user1164061 Try the configuration mapping "default->*". Perhaps the dependencies are scoped as either test or optional.

Comment: Really appreciate your answer with multiple options to try. This didnt solve my problem though. So I am going to explicitly list all of them. Thanks.