# Excluding an Ivy dependency conditionally

Tags: java, ant, ivy

I need to build a custom Ant script that builds a project based on CI output. We use Atlassian Bamboo as CI server.

Normally our projects have a dependency to our platform module, managed via Ivy/Artifactory.

Our typical `dependencies.xml` file contains a dependency to *that* module, transitively. **And** other potential dependencies. As an example, our core module depends on lots of Spring packages, but not on Spring Boot. If a project needs Spring Boot too, it will define its dependency in its `dependencies.xml` file along with `<depencency org="com.acme" name="core-platform"...`

My goal now is to exclude `com.acme#core-platform` from resolution, because I am making a different task that uses Bamboo output artifact to take the latest build of the core module and its dependencies **without** going through Artifactory.

This is very important because during a build I may like to change the version of a dependent package (e.g. upgrade Spring 4.3.1 to 4.3.3) and test with the proper Spring. If I simply resolve dependencies to `com.acme#core-platform#latest.release`, which is released on Artifactory, I won't take 4.3.3 of Spring which was committed to Git and available in `core-platform`'s currently-building `dependencies.xml`. I hope my explanation is easy to understand.

So let's say I have this dependency list as an example

```
    com.acme#core-platform#${version}
    org.hibernate#hibernate-java8#5.1.0.Final
    org.springframework.boot#spring-boot-starter-web#1.3.1.RELEASE
    commons-collections#commons-collections#3.2.2
    .... others
```

Full dependency is

```
<dependencies>  
    <dependency org="com.acme"              name="core-platform"          rev="${version}"         transitive="true"      conf="runtime->runtime" changing="true"/>
    <dependency org="com.acme"              name="core-platform"          rev="${version}"         transitive="true"      conf="compile->compile" changing="true"/>
    <dependency org="com.acme"              name="core-platform"          rev="${version}"         transitive="true"      conf="provided->provided" changing="true"/>
    <dependency org="com.acme"              name="core-platform"          rev="${version}"         transitive="true"      conf="junit->junit" changing="true"/>
    <dependency org="com.acme"              name="core-platform"          rev="${version}"         transitive="true"      conf="test->test" changing="true"/>



    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-java8 -->
    <dependency org="org.hibernate" name="hibernate-java8" rev="5.1.0.Final" transitive="false" />


    <dependency org="org.springframework.boot"  name="spring-boot-starter-web"          rev="1.3.1.RELEASE"                 transitive="false" />
    <dependency org="org.springframework.boot"  name="spring-boot-starter-tomcat"       rev="1.3.1.RELEASE"                 transitive="false" />
    <dependency org="org.springframework.boot"  name="spring-boot-starter-validation"   rev="1.3.1.RELEASE"                 transitive="false" />


    <dependency org="commons-collections"               name="commons-collections"              rev="3.2.2"             transitive="false" />


    <!-- jackson2 libs -->
    <dependency org="com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype"    name="jackson-datatype-jdk8"            rev="2.8.1"             transitive="false"          conf="runtime->*"/>
    <dependency org="com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype"    name="jackson-datatype-jsr310"          rev="2.8.1"             transitive="false"          conf="runtime->*"/>


    <exclude module="joda-time" />
    <exclude module="jackson-datatype-joda" />
</dependencies>
```

I simply want to take Hibernates' Java8, commons-collections, etc.

1. Creating a duplicate dependencies.xml is **not** an option
2. I was considering manipulating the dependencies.xml via Ant and have it exclude the `acme` modules by regex. Feasible but tricky
3. Unfortunately I can't combine Ant task's `ivy:retrieve` with attributes `file` and element `exclude`, because that would have helped a looooooot

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to understand your requirement. I suspect that your problem could be solved by creating an additional configuration and use configuration mappings to control the downloads.

## Example

This build creates two directories. The first contains the log4j dependency without transitive dependencies, the second includes the remote module's optional dependencies. If you look at the remote POM you'll see they have a different scope.

```
├── build.xml
├── ivy.xml
├── lib1
│   └── log4j-1.2.17.jar
└── lib2
    ├── activation-1.1.jar
    ├── geronimo-jms_1.1_spec-1.0.jar
    ├── log4j-1.2.17.jar
    └── mail-1.4.3.jar
```

### build.xml

```
<project name="demo" default="resolve" xmlns:ivy="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant">

  <target name="resolve">
    <ivy:resolve/>

    <ivy:retrieve pattern="lib1/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]" conf="noDependencies"/>
    <ivy:retrieve pattern="lib2/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]" conf="withDependencies"/>
  </target>

</project>
```

Notes:

- Each "retrieve" task creates a directory containing the files that make up the configuration.

### ivy.xml

```
<ivy-module version="2.0">
  <info organisation="com.myspotontheweb" module="demo"/>

  <configurations>
    <conf name="noDependencies" description="File grouping that has no transitive dependencies"/>
    <conf name="withDependencies" description="File grouping that contains dependencies"/>
  </configurations>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency org="log4j" name="log4j" rev="1.2.17" conf="noDependencies->master; withDependencies->master,optional"/>
  </dependencies>

</ivy-module>
```

Notes:

- Note how the configuration is declared at the top of the ivy file and the dependency contains two configuration mappings

---

## Additional

The following answer explains how ivy interprets Maven modules. It creates configurations that can be used to decide which files should be downloaded:

- [How are maven scopes mapped to ivy configurations by ivy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7104364/how-are-maven-scopes-mapped-to-ivy-configurations-by-ivy/7116577#7116577)

Answer (score -1):

Ok, looks like the replace trick is very easy too.

1. Add the following markers `<!-- DEPS START -->` and `<!-- DEPS END -->` (or any of choice) between the parts of the dependencies.xml file to ignore
2. Hack via Ant

   ```
   <copy file="dependencies.xml" tofile="ci/hacked-dependencies.xml" overwrite="true">
       <filterchain>
           <replacestring from="&lt;!-- DEPS START --&gt;" to="&lt;!--" />
           <replacestring from="&lt;!-- DEPS END --&gt;" to="--&gt;" />
       </filterchain>
   </copy>
   ```

Example

```
    <!-- DEPS START --> 
    <dependency org="com.acme" name="core-platfrom" rev="${version}" transitive="true" conf="runtime->runtime"/>
    <!-- DEPS END -->
```

Comment: I suspect there is a better solution. You appear to be using configurations, why don't you create an additional mapping? What confuses me is that in some places you have a configuration mapping and in other places you have set transitive to be false.

Comment: Yea, the `transitive=false` is an old policy **dictated** by the boss. It has a sense, however: we are always required to have full control of dependencies, so upgrading the version of a package must not involve hidden unlisted dependencies. Anyway, upgrading is still a pain in our environment

Comment: When downloading from a Maven repository a mapping to the remote "master" configuration will download the arifact without dependencies. Secondly you need to consider using configurations in order to download different groupings of dependencies. I have included an example in my answer. I hope it helps clarify how ivy works and assists in solving your problem