# Java - Apache Ivy not resolving dependencies correctly

Tags: java, ant, ivy

I am unable to compile source with Ant via terminal as it seems like dependencies are not resolved correctly despite me issuing 'ant resolve or ant retrieve'?

My build.xml and ivy.xml below

**build.xml**

```
<!-- ANT HOME ENVIRONMENT VARIABLE -->
<property name="ant.home" value="${env.ANT_HOME}" />

<!-- IVY HOME DIRECTORY -->
<property name="ivy.home" value="${ant.home}" />

<!-- IVY2 JAR DIRECTORY (REPOSITORY) -->
<property name="ivy.default.ivy.user.dir" value="${user.home}/.ivy2"/>

<!-- DOWNLOAD IVY -->
<target name="setup" description="Install ivy">
    <mkdir dir="${user.home}/.ivy2" />
    <get dest="${ivy.home}/lib/ivy.jar" src="http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/apache/ivy/ivy/2.3.0/ivy-2.3.0.jar"/>
</target>

<!-- RESOLVE CLASSPATHS -->
<target name="resolve" description="Use ivy to resolve classpaths">
    <ivy:resolve file="ivy.xml" />
    <ivy:report todir='target/ivy-reports' graph='false' xml='false'/>
    <ivy:cachepath pathid="ivy.path" conf="compile" />
</target>

<!-- RETRIEVE DEPENDANCIES AFTER RESOLVING-->
<target name="retrieve" depends="resolve" description="Use ivy to retrieve dependencies">
    <ivy:retrieve sync="true" type="jar" />
</target>

<!-- COMPILE PROJECT -->
<target name="compile" depends="clean, retrieve">
    <!-- Create build directory -->
    <mkdir dir="target/${ant.project.name}" />

    <!-- Compile source code -->
    <javac includeantruntime="false" srcdir="src" debug="true" destdir="target/${ant.project.name}" >
        <classpath>
            <path refid="ivy.path" />
        </classpath>
    </javac>
</target>

<!-- CLEAN TARGET DIRECTORY -->
<target name="clean">
    <delete dir="target/orderlycalls" />
    <delete dir="target/classes" />
    <delete dir="target/ivy-reports" />     
</target>

<!-- CLEAN TARGET AND IVY CATCHE -->
<target name="clean-all" depends="clean" description="Additionally purge ivy cache">
    <ivy:cleancache/>
</target>
```

**ivy.xml**

```
<ivy-module version="2.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/schemas/ivy.xsd">

    <configurations>
        <conf name="default" visibility="public" description="The single built artifact. Nothing else"/>
        <conf name="compile" visibility="public" description="The master module and transitive dependencies"/>
        <conf name="provided" visibility="public" description="Needed for compile. Will be provided outside or war"/>
        <conf name="runtime" visibility="public" description="Not required for compile, but for runtime" extends="compile"/>
        <conf name="default" visibility="public" description="The default configuration" extends="runtime"/>
        <conf name="test" visibility="private" description="Required for testing" extends="runtime"/>
    </configurations>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency org="net.sf.trove4j" name="trove4j" rev="3.0.3" conf="provided"/>
        <dependency org="org.apache.tomcat.embed" name="tomcat-embed-core" rev="7.0.53" conf="provided"/>
    </dependencies>

</ivy-module>
```

when i run 'ant compile' the on compilation ant is complaining that it can not find 'Servlet Context' which is part of tomcat.jar or 'TObject', 'THashMap' which are part of trove.jar and many more despite the fact that i am retrieving/resolving the jars in build.xml.

Another thing i have noticed is that inside my .ivy2/cache// there are no actual jar files. Only xml files

Any idea what i am doing wrong or not doing at all ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used the cachepath task to create an Ant Path, using dependencies associated with the "compile" configuration.

```
<ivy:cachepath pathid="ivy.path" conf="compile" />
```

Your issue lies with your ivy file, where you haven't specified any dependencies with a mapping to the "compile" configuration. This would explain why your javac task cannot see any jars.

```
   <configurations>
        ...
        <conf name="compile" .../>
        <conf name="provided" .../>
        ...
    </configurations>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency ... conf="provided"/>
        <dependency ... conf="provided"/>
    </dependencies>
```

I suggest creating an explicit mapping for each of your configurations, for example:

```
<!-- Compile dependencies --> 
<dependency org="net.sf.trove4j" name="trove4j" rev="3.0.3" conf="compile->default"/>

<!-- provided dependencies -->
<dependency org="org.apache.tomcat.embed" name="tomcat-embed-core" rev="7.0.53" conf="provided->master"/>
```

The only mappings you'll ever need are to the following remote configurations:

- **default** Remote jar plus its transitive dependencies
- **master** Remote jar only

For more information on how ivy interprets remote maven modules please read the following:

- [How are maven scopes mapped to ivy configurations by ivy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7104364/how-are-maven-scopes-mapped-to-ivy-configurations-by-ivy/7116577#7116577)