# With Ivy, how retrieve the configurations of dependencies?

Tags: ivy

After reading this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652555/can-someone-explain-the-ivy-xml-dependencys-conf-attribute), I don't understand how we can find the configuration of the dependencies.
More precisely, in the example below, how retrieve the configurations (proxool,oscache) of hibernate ?

```
<dependency org="hibernate" name="hibernate" rev="2.1.8" conf="default->proxool,oscache"/>
```

Comment: retrieve or resolve? What exactly does not work?

Comment: If I understand correctly proxool and oscache are defined in ivy.xml file of hibernate. How do you retrieve this information ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to look into hibernate's *ivy.xml* to see the list of all published configurations. Either you resolve the dependency and take a look into your local cache, or you can view the ivy.xml directly in the repository you are using.

Note: When you resolve from a maven repo there will be some translation/mapping from the POM to the ivy.xml.

Comment: Ok thanks. It's not very user friendly. Perhaps in Intellij there is a plugin to speed up this...

Comment: @Ekans As Andy stated when using a Maven repo you can make assumptions about the remote configurations, because Maven has a number of fixed "scopes" which are mapped to equivolent ivy configurations. This makes things more predictable. See the following answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7104364/how-are-maven-scopes-mapped-to-ivy-configurations-by-ivy/7116577#7116577